# Embed table section as container in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interface-builder

My application currently has one large static table view for it's settings screen. This static table view has several different groups/sections. During the first use of the app, I would like to only present certain sections of that tableview at a time, so that the user isn't overwhelmed. Some of the sections are optional and not particularly important to a new user.

I would like to create a separate view for each settings group/section, and then embed those sections into different table views as needed. In other words, I would like these sections to be self-contained reusable components.

Does anybody know how I would do this? Dragging a container into a tableview doesn't seem to work in the interface builder.

UPDATE:
I tried creating a view with a scroll view inside of it. I then tried creating multiple single-group table views and embedded them inside the scroll view. Unfortunately, the scroll view doesn't actually scroll with this setup (even though it looks correct).

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to create a separate view for each settings group/section, and then embed those sections into different table views as needed. In other words, I would like these sections to be self-contained reusable components.

Well, you can't. A table is a table. It works how it works. If you don't want to show the optional sections, just omit them from the data model when you tell the table what its data is. You can change the data model and reload the table at any time. Think in terms of the data *model* being self-contained reusable components, not the table.

Comment: The table is not being populated from a data model. It's a static table with fields for the user to fill out. An example, one of the sections is Personal Information, with a full name and phone number field

Comment: @Noah Stop and think what you're saying. Think about the words "static" and "dynamic". _They are opposites._ You want sections to come and go _dynamically_. If sections can come and go dynamically, then the table _is not static_. It's as simple as that. You cannot do what you want to do purely with a static table. - You could do it using _two different_ static tables, maybe, if that would satisfy your needs. But my advice is: face reality, drop the whole static table idea, and do what I said in my answer: concentrate on making the _model_ easy to modify.

Comment: I don't mind making it dynamic, but how would I go about creating different dynamic sections? This isn't driven by core data, it's just some text fields and switches

Comment: Have you ever written a dynamic table before? You are asked Three Big Questions: how many sections, how many rows in each sections, and the cell for each row. If you have fewer sections, give a small answer to the first question! It's just a question of devising a flexible data model, as I said before. If the data model is correctly written, the Three Big Questions just look at the data model and give the answer immediately based on that. The sections are clumps of _data_ that you insert into or remove from your _data model_.